# Simplification of $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{z^{n-1}s^{n}}{(n-1)!n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

How can I simplify $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{z^{n-1}s^{n}}{(n-1)!n!}$ for $z$ and $s$ positive real numbers ?
I thought about finding a function $f$ such that $f^{n}(0) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \forall n$.
I also thought about representing the sum as the inner product of two vectors with components of the exponential in an Hilbert space.

Comment: Looks like some kind of Bessel function.

Comment: This is a mild modification of the $I$ Bessel function. The way to know that it's in the class of Bessel functions is the appearance of two factorials and the way to know it is $I$ is that the terms are not alternating.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{sz}} I_{1}(2\sqrt{sz})$$

Comment: Thanks, I obtained the same formula